# How to write regexp to match the longest candidate in elisp?

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I am trying to write a function to remove suffix from a string. The suffix  is listed below:

```
agent_pkg
agent
pkg
driver
abs_if
abs_if_pkg
if_pkg
if
```

Test string:

```
test_blah_agent_pkg
test_blah_agent
test_blah_pkg
test_blah_driver
test_blah_abs_if
test_blah_abs_if_pkg
test_blah_if_pkg
test_blah_if
```

From the above test string, I expect to get `test_blah` from it.

I wrote a function like this:

```
(defun get-base-name (name)
  "Get the base name from string."
  (setq s (substring-no-properties name))
  (string-match "\\(.*\\)_\\(agent_pkg\\|agent\\|driver\\|abs_if\\|if\\|pkg\\)" s)  
  (match-string 1 s))
```

but it always just match the short candicates. I got `test_blah_abs` from `(get-base-name "test_blah_abs")`

Comment: try `"\\([^_]*_[^_]*\\)_.*`

Comment: Hi @AvinashRaj, I think I may not present my question clearly. the `test_blah` can be any format and any length.

Comment: i think you forget to add some more extensions. It always better to add `$` end of the line anchor at the last.

Comment: Incidentally, make sure you're only calling `match-string` if the `string-match` result was non-`nil`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.*` is greedy¹, meaning it would try to cover as much as possible, as long as the string matches the regex. You want to make it non-greedy, to stop as soon as the match is found. Adding `?` just after `*` or `+` makes it non-greedy. Compare:

```
(let ((s "abcabcabc"))
  (string-match ".*c" s)
  (match-string 0 s)) ; => "abcabcabc"
(let ((s "abcabcabc"))
  (string-match ".*?c" s)
  (match-string 0 s)) ; => "abc"
```

`.*?` is a non-greedy version of `.*`, so just adding `?` makes it work:

```
(let ((s "test_blah_agent_pkg
test_blah_agent
test_blah_pkg
test_blah_driver
test_blah_abs_if
test_blah_abs_if_pkg
test_blah_if_pkg
test_blah_if"))
  (string-match "\\(.*?\\)_\\(agent_pkg\\|agent\\|driver\\|abs_if\\|if\\|pkg\\)" s)
  (match-string 1 s)) ; => "test_blah"
```

[FYI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FYI), third-party string manipulation library [**`s`**](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) has plenty of string functions that you mind useful instead of relying on regular expressions all the time. E.g. [`s-shared-start`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-shared-start-s1-s2) can find a common prefix for 2 strings:

```
(s-shared-start "test_blah_agent" "test_blah_pkg") ; "test_blah_"
```

Combined with [`s-lines`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-lines-s), which breaks a string into a list of strings by newline character, and [`-reduce`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-reduce-fn-list) function from the amazing third-party list manipulation library [**`dash`**](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el), you can find a prefix that is common for every string:

```
(let ((s "test_blah_agent_pkg
test_blah_agent
test_blah_pkg
test_blah_driver
test_blah_abs_if
test_blah_abs_if_pkg
test_blah_if_pkg
test_blah_if"))
  (-reduce 's-shared-start (s-lines s))) ; => "test_blah_"
```

¹ Read [under section *Greediness*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/596361) to understand this concept.

Comment: Hi @sindikat. thanks for your answer. It solved my problem. The other options with `s` may not work for this case because every time I only have single string try to match with the suffixes. But there's a lot of knowledge in your reply. I will read the packages you listed carefully. Thanks again.